# Error while Trying to print the contents of list consisting more than one dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I get the following error for the print statements. What is incorrect about the dictionary?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/main.py", line 8, in 
>   "enabled": true,                                                                                                NameError: name 'true' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ...Program finished with exit code 1
>   Press ENTER to exit console.

---

```
gcblist =[
{
    "band": "5",
    "channel": 155,
    "clients": 0,
    "country": "United States",
    "device": "wlan0",
    "enabled": true,
    "fbo": false,
    "fbo_active": false,
    "name": "5.0GHz",
    "ssids": [
        "TestWiFi"
    ],
    "txpower": "30"
},
{
    "band": "2.4",
    "channel": 1,
    "clients": 0,
    "country": "United States",
    "device": "wlan1",
    "enabled": true,
    "fbo": true,
    "fbo_active": false,
    "name": "2.4GHz",
    "ssids": [
        "TestWiFi"
    ],
    "txpower": "30"
}
]  
for item in gcblist:  
    print (item)  
    print (item['device'])
```

Comment: Did you read the error code? It tells you the problem. You don't have any variable named `true`. The boolean object you're looking for is, as blhsing mentions in his answer, is `True`, not `true`. Same for `False` vs `false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'true' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30095032/nameerror-name-true-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did find out after I posted the issue here. I was thinking in terms of key/value pairs in a dictionary and was expecting all of the data in it to free form.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you should use `True` and `False` for Boolean values of true and false:

```
gcblist =[
{
    "band": "5",
    "channel": 155,
    "clients": 0,
    "country": "United States",
    "device": "wlan0",
    "enabled": True,
    "fbo": False,
    "fbo_active": False,
    "name": "5.0GHz",
    "ssids": [
        "TestWiFi"
    ],
    "txpower": "30"
},
{
    "band": "2.4",
    "channel": 1,
    "clients": 0,
    "country": "United States",
    "device": "wlan1",
    "enabled": True,
    "fbo": True,
    "fbo_active": False,
    "name": "2.4GHz",
    "ssids": [
        "TestWiFi"
    ],
    "txpower": "30"
}
```